# c# access database program

Tags: c#, ms-access, dao

```
String strSql = "insert into BaseData (Item," + dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name + "," + dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name + ") values ('" + row.Cells[0].Value + "','" + row.Cells[3].Value + "','" + row.Cells[4].Value + "')";                        

objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, lConn);  
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

strSql = "select id from BaseData where Item = '" + row.Cells[0].Value + "' and " + dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name + " = '" + row.Cells[3].Value + "' And " + dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name + " = '" + row.Cells[4].Value + "'";

OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(strSql, lConn);                           
OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();   
String id = "";   
while (reader.Read())
{  
  id = reader.GetString(0);
}    
reader.Close();

strSql = "insert into tranjaction (Base_id,quentity,price,other) values ('" + id + "' , ' " + row.Cells[2].Value + "','" + row.Cells[1].Value + "')";

objCmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, lConn);  
objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

---

When I run this, Microsoft Visual Studio Error occur on Line 10. (ExecuteReader)

The Error is here.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: No value given for one or more required
>   parameters.

How could I fix this error?.

Comment: Have you checked what this line ends up as `strSql = "select id from BaseData where Item = '" + row.Cells[0].Value + "' and " + dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name + " = '" + row.Cells[3].Value + "' And " + dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name + " = '" + row.Cells[4].Value + "'";` are all the fields (columns) text, because according to this, they should be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your field names are wrong (quentity?) or it's because you have unbalanced fields to parameters.  You are inserting into 4 fields, but you are only supplying 3 values.  Use parameters instead, it would make your life easier.

Try changing it to this:

```
strSql = "insert into tranjaction (Base_id,quentity,price,other) values (@id , @quentity, @price, @other)";
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sqlSql, IConn)) {
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quentity", row.Cells[2].Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", row.Cells[1].Value);
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@other", other);  //  <- missing
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Error occured on Line6, not Line 15.

Comment: @bTagTiger That is something you should've mentioned in the question. And also which line is line 6

Comment: @bTagTiger I'm guessing Line 6 is referring to "@other"-- I don't know what other is, but you have it in your query, so I assume you know what it is.  If it's not needed, then remove that line, but then you have to take it out of your SQL string, too.

Answer (score 1):

In this line

```
strSql = "insert into tranjaction (Base_id,quentity,price,other) values ('" + id + "' , ' " + row.Cells[2].Value + "','" + row.Cells[1].Value + "')";
```

you are inserting 4 values (Base_id,quentity,price,other), but you are only inserting 3 values (id, row.Cells[2].Value, row.Cells[1].Value). Giving a value for `other` should fix the problem.

Another thing that would cause this error, which is probably your situation, is if you've spelled one of the column names incorrectly. And since you are using column names from your datagridview, and some of your written column names seem mis-spelled, you should double check the spelling in your query strings.

Comment: @bTagTiger You say the error occurred on line 6, you should check the query string right above that `"select id from BaseData where...` at runtime and make sure all your field names/values are correctly spelled

Comment: Well, I've already checked strSql at runtime and every value is correct.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4524/discussion-between-shredder-and-btagtiger)

Answer (score 1):

When I've received this error in the past it has always been because of a simple typo. Like the others have mentioned it looks like you spelled "quantity" wrong which could be part of the problem.

Comment: I made an query in Microsoft Access by use strSql's content. And found no problem. Query works good.

Comment: I have no time. Please help me as soon as possible quickly.